# render text with escape squence (like a terminal)

Tags: bash, text, terminal, render, vi

### Hi, I'm looking for some lib or tool to render text with escape squence chars in a text file. I dont know how to call this, but here is a example:

```
~$ echo -e "abc\vdef"
abc
   def
~$
~$ echo -e "abc\vdef" > /tmp/xxxxx
~$ vi /tmp/xxxxx
```

I got abc^Kdef on screen.

so i'm searching some tool that can do this for me:

```
~$ sometool /tmp/xxxxx > /tmp/yyyyy
~$ vi /tmp/yyyyy
I can get 

abc
   def
```

in vi window.

\v is just a example, I need convert \v, \b, \f, etc.

to harithski:
but what I want is:

```
$~/:sometool /tmp/xxxxx > /tmp/yyyyy
```

in python

```
>>> f=open('/tmp/yyyyyy').readlines()
>>> f[0]
>>> ['abc\n   def']
```

which has three space between \n and def

Answer (score 0):

the character \v in shell is represented differently in each editor/tool. If you do a cat of the file, you still get what you need

```
$ cat /tmp/xxxxx
abc
   def
$
```

If you open the same file in python, you will see the character as \x0b. But when you print it, it is fine.

```
>>> f=open('/tmp/se').readlines()
>>> f[0]
['abc\x0bdef\n']
>>> print f[0]
abc
   def
```

Basically it is a matter of representation. If your requirement is to read the file using a program or tool, the representation shouldn't be a problem.

Comment: printing is not enough, as the escape sequences are still in the output (even if they're hidden):

For example, I'd like to search for a string in a terminal log and only search for strings actually displayed, eg:


    `$script terminal_log.txt
    >>logging to terminal_log.txt
    $echo bar<BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE><BACKSPACE>foo
    >>foo
    $cat terminal_log.txt|grep bar|wc -l
    >>1`

I expected 0 instead of 1 since bar was deleted. (sorry for formatting, but stackoverflow doesn't allow line breaks in comments)

Answer (score -1):

Don't think I'm entirely understanding the question, but is `od` going to help?

Example:

```
$ echo -e "abc\vdef" > temp
$ cat temp
abcdef
$ od -c temp 
0000000   a   b   c  \v   d   e   f  \n
0000010
```

You could pipe that output through sed if you wanted to clean it up. Like I said, I'm not sure that's what you're asking.

Comment: cleaning with sed won't work as the terminal sequence may be quite complex, such as clearing screen, backspace etc.

Comment: That's what od is for. clear screen or backspace will come out of od as `\f`, `\b` or `FF`, `BS` depending on the option. I was only suggesting sed for formatting `od`'s output.

Comment: I don't want to just remove special control sequences, I want to interpret them (see all use cases).